# xcode 13 provisional profile expired

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have an iOS application with the Development provisional profile which is about to get expired.
I no longer have the access to the account which created the Development provisional profile and certificate.
I need to run the application on multiple devices.

What is the solution?

Comment: Get access to the developer account again or get access to a different developer account and change the bundle id

Comment: If I register with different Developer account, and create provisional profile, certificate with different bundle Id that would work?

Comment: Yes, but it will be different app as far as your device and the App Store is concerned